# No static method setSoKeepalive() Error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-gradle-plugin, text-to-speech, aws-sdk

I am trying to implement the Ivona TTS engine in my android app.

However I keep on getting this error. There seems to be a compatible problem between the Ivona/AWS sdk and android .

Any idea ? Here is my code and gradle

Error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setSoKeepalive(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V in class Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
                                                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:95)
                                                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:198)
                                                                                 at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:129)
                                                                                 at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:113)
                                                                                 at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.<init>(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:152)
                                                                                 at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.<init>(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:141)
                                                                                 at ivonatestsecond.com.ivonasecond.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                                 at ivonatestsecond.com.ivonasecond.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Init:

```
 private static void init() {
    speechCloud = new IvonaSpeechCloudClient(new IvonaCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx"));
    speechCloud.setEndpoint("https://tts.eu-west-1.ivonacloud.com");
}
```

IvonaCredentials class

```
public class IvonaCredentials implements AWSCredentialsProvider {

public IvonaCredentials(String mSecretKey, String mAccessKey) {
    super();
    this.mSecretKey = mSecretKey;
    this.mAccessKey = mAccessKey;
}

private String mSecretKey;
private String mAccessKey;

@Override
public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials() {

        @Override
        public String getAWSSecretKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mSecretKey;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mAccessKey;
        };
    };
    return awsCredentials;
}

@Override
public void refresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.ivona:ivona-speechcloud-sdk-java:1.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Why is the init() method static? Did you try not making it static?

Comment: No thats not it. It has to do with the Ivona sdk ....

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. It should be the problem of the SDK. Even removing `static` from variable & functions, the problem still exists internally in their SDK.

Comment: Did you solve this? Or are you still stuck? Its ridicules to think of a company like Ivona who is backed by Amazon doesn't have a working SDK for android....

Comment: Also having the same exact issue as you are.  No one can figure this out? I am using the same Credential code  since for some reason i was getting this weird prolog error, but now i'm at the same place as you are.

Comment: Let me know if you figured a work around here. Would love to know!

Comment: Does any one get the solution of above?